Gradle error ("unknown property 'targetsdkversion' ") after importing library (Android Studio)
I want to import the API Library for Organic Maps (https://github.com/organicmaps/api-android/)
I downloaded the repository as a zip file and extracted the contents. The instructions for the download state that the "lib" folder 'is a library project that you should add to your project. You don't need any additional permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml to use API library, so you can write real code straight away, calling for different Api methods" '
In Android Studio I went to File>New>Import Module and in the "Import module from source" window pointed the "Source directory" to the "lib" folder from the download. I then named the lib/module "OrganicMaps".
After doing that Gradle ran but failed with the following messages:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':OrganicMaps'.
Could not get unknown property 'targetSdkVersion' for project
':OrganicMaps' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Exception is: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred
evaluating project ':OrganicMaps'. at
org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
....

Have I not imported the module correctly? Any advice, please?

I assume you already clicked the sync button on Gradle and imported the project right? implementation project(':OrganicMaps')

I assumed that when Gradle ran automatically it would do all the syncing necessary! Do you mean the "Sync Project with Gradle files" near the top right of the Window. I've clicked that and it says "BUILD SUCCESSFUL". Thank you!

Yes, I meant the Refresh Button on the right top side. Once I lost also my libraries and it brought everything back. You're welcome. Cheers!
